# Creating and slow representing a large amount of TLabel runtime

Tags: performance, delphi, runtime, delphi-xe2

In my application i work with `TLabel` objects runtime.

There is a problem: representing a 20 labels takes a lot time (about a 1-2 second).

DoubleBuffered on parent component doesn't help. `Application.ProcessMessages` only allows watching for a proccess of creating, instead of looking at frosen window.

```
// creating a labels in loop 
aLabel:=TLabel.Create(scrlbx);
labels.Add(aLabel); // TList for managing.
with aLabel do begin
Left:=pointLeft;
    Top:=pointTop;
    Caption:='title';
    parent:=scrlbx; //TScrollBox
end;
pointTop:=pointTop+20;
```

Taking parent assigning out of loop to another loop after does some effect, but does'n solve the problem.

```
for I := 0 to labels.Count-1 do begin
    TLabel(labels[i]).Parent:= scrlbx;
end;
```

Disable and enable `TScrollBox.Visible` before and aftel loops has no effect.

PS:
Creting of objects doesn't takes a time.
The bottleneck is parent assigning.

upd: large amount means about 500 items..

Comment: Can't confirm the issue; tested and 1000 labels were created in a scrollbox in an eye wink.

Comment: I also tested with 2000... less than one second... but... if I activate a *custom style*, the time spent blow up...

Comment: Do you have a conditional break point and compiling for 64 bit? I noticed that's something to be avoided if possible..

Comment: I have not any conditional break point and compile for 32. I haven't changed any project settings except icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ScrollBox.DisableAlign` and `.EnabledAlign`.

```
procedure TForm1.CreateLabels2;
var
  I: Integer;
  ALabel: TLabel;
  ATop: Integer;
begin
  ATop := 0;
  ScrollBox2.DisableAlign;
  for I := 0 to 2000 do
  begin
    ALabel := TLabel.Create(ScrollBox2);
    FLabels.Add(ALabel);
    with ALabel do
    begin
      Caption := 'Title';
      SetBounds(0, ATop, Width, Height);
      Parent := ScrollBox2;
    end;
    Inc(ATop, 20);
  end;
  ScrollBox2.EnableAlign;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: The cause is that, while align is enabled new label calls realling method for any previosly created ones, isn't it?

Comment: @yujin1st Yes, simply said that is true. But there is no such thing as a _Reallign method_, more a complete _Reallign framework_.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just creating 20 `TLabel`, adding an `Application.Processmessages` is not a good idea because it will repaint it to immediately show the new added components...

With a regular application, it takes less than 1 seconds to generate 2000 `TLabel`...
If I set a custom style, it takes longer... maybe, this is your issue...

So, to have a quick generation, I did it like this:

```
uses ...,  System.StrUtils, System.Diagnostics, Vcl.Themes, Vcl.Styles;


procedure TForm3.GenerateLabels(bNoStyle: Boolean);
var
  iLoop, iMax: Integer;
  aLabel     : TLabel;
  pointLeft  : Integer;
  pointTop   : Integer;
  timeSpent  : TStopwatch;
begin
  iMax      := 2000;
  pointLeft :=  3;
  pointTop  :=  3;
  timeSpent := TStopwatch.StartNew;     // how long does it take
  if bNoStyle then
    TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Windows'); // = no style
  for iLoop := 1 to iMax do
  begin
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    // creating a labels in loop
    aLabel:=TLabel.Create(Self);
    labels.Add(aLabel); // TList for managing.
    with aLabel do
    begin
      Left    := pointLeft;
      Top     := pointTop;
      Caption := 'title';
      parent  := scrlbx1; //TScrollBox
    end;
    pointTop  := pointTop + 20;
  end;
  if bNoStyle then
    TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Carbon');  // previous style
  labels[0].Caption := IfThen(bNoStyle, 'No style', 'Style');
  labels[1].Caption := IntToStr(timeSpent.ElapsedMilliseconds) + 'ms';   // display the spent time
  labels[2].Caption := IntToStr(labels.Count);
  timeSpent.Stop;
end;
```

[image: With a style]
[image: If I desactivate the style]

Comment: Yes, i use a custom style for labels. And Enable/Disable Align quickly solves a problem. Your variant also solves a problem, but takes a little more time for applying